# Как вынести style часть в отдельный модуль(файл)?

Tags: c#, xaml, style, resources

Скажите пожалуйста как мне вынести из `mainwindow.xaml` все `style-ресурсы` в отдельный файл чтоб аж глаз радовался :D , а то просто тяжело в коде ориентироваться когда у тебя ресурсы в main файле занимают 50% от всего кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле App.xaml должен быть такой код:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="путь_к_файлу/имя_файла.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```